# Get the following Monday with a specific timestamp

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have the following formula that gets the following monday if the date falls on a saturday. However, I need to be able to get the monday with a timestamp of 00:00:00 AM.
The current cell has a timestamp of 4/15/18 18:47:11 PM and the formula returns 4/16/18 18:47:11 PM. I need it to return 4/16/18 00:00:00 AM

```
=IF(MOD(WEEKDAY(D1),7)=1,D1+1,"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw in a TRUNC.

`=IF(MOD(WEEKDAY(D1),7)=1,TRUNC(D1+1,0),"")`